# Is there a way to list all the node modules back to package.json?

Tags: npm, node-modules, package.json

Is there a way to list node modules back to package.json file?

I'm a college student and currently working on a group project, and since we are all new, we often copy node modules here and there, so when I run `npm i`, it won't get all the dependencies, is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [dependency-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-check) it checks which modules you have used in your code and then makes sure they are listed as dependencies in your `package.json`, or vice-versa.

Hopefully that helps!